# Convert a string of dates with missing values

Tags: python, datetime

This may be formulated into a more general question, but the problem I have is like this: I want to convert a string of dates into datetime objects, but the string contains empty dates. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2000.02.25', ''], 'B': ['', '2003.05.26']})
```

I want the returned dataframe to keep the empty dates as `NaN` or `NaT`. For the sake of speed, I do not want to use `pd.to_datetime`, which works otherwise perfectly but is a magnitude slower compared to `datetime.datetime`:

```
df['A'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y.%m.%d') for x in df['A']]
```

However, the problem is how to deal with the empty strings. If I include an `if len(x) > 0` condition, the returned list will be of different length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['A'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y.%m.%d') if x else pd.NaT for x in df['A']]
```

The construct `a if cond else b` can be used outside of list comprehensions, it's python's ternary operator.

I'm also a bit surprised `df = df.astype(pd.datetime)` doesn't win out, but my guess is that it's hitting an exception on every empty row. This performance hit may be bug-worthy.

Comment: Thanks @U2EF1 ! This is exactly the answer I am looking for. I tested with no empty columns, `pd.to_datetime` is still a magnitude slower. In fact, the clear winner is `[dt.datetime(int(x[:4]), int(x[5:7]), int(x[8:10])) for x in df['A']]`.

Comment: I think the difference is mainly due to `pd.to_datetime` takes time to interpret the format of the string. If the input strings are in `isoformat`, `pd.to_datetime` is only moderately slower than `dt.datetime.strptime`. In the above example, `%timeit` shows the time as `78.4 µs` vs `57 µs`.